# Apache: How do I re-route all requests to a single file?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, single-page-application

I'm writing a static single page Backbone site with a single entry point: index.html

I've been told that because of this, I need to re-route all requests to my url e.g. www.example.com/*, to that index.html file. So, if someone types in www.example.com/lolnotreal, I need that request to be redirected to /index.html but in a manner which my index.html file still could pick up the url attempted, in the example's case: /lolnotreal

Is this even possible considering it's just an html file? Basically I need for backbone to pick up the url attempted.

Thanks for any help

Dearest downvoter: Please explain. I'm not a server expert and my hours of attempts at using .htaccess have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

that does it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this lines to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\/\_]{1,})$
RewriteRule [^/]*/(([a-zA-Z0-9\/\_]{1,}){0,})$ /index.html?q1=$0 [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. If i use the url www.example.com/anything, I get a "Not Found" error. I need www.example.com/anything to go to index.html, but still show www.example.com/anything in the url title, if that makes any sense.